# adding number to a QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, short, qbytearray

i have a `QbyteArray`  named `"B2"`,

and i want to add  to this a 2byte number like `300`.

but when i do that `mybyte.size()` become `3byte!!!!`

my code is :

i want to it become 2byte.

```
    QByteArray B2;
        short int myint;
        myint=300;
        B2.setNum(myint);
qDebug()<<B2[0]<<B2.size();
```

and this is my output:

```
3 3
```

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qbytearray.html#details):

> **QByteArray::setNum()** sets the byte array to the printed value of n in base base (10 by default) and returns a reference to the byte array. The base can be any value between 2 and 36.

It is obvious that it gives you a size of 3, since you the set an array of 3 bytes.

## update

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  B2.append(myint >> (i * 8));
}
```

Comment: ok , but i want to have a QbyteArray that Byte 1 and Byte 2 are for a 2Byte number and Byte3 to Byte n are for another data  , now if we do it if my number was 2  then my QbyteArray will lost his form? ! do you understand? what i say?

Comment: what can i do to fix every number (0-511) to byte 0 and byte 1 of my Qbytearray?

Comment: you have to "transform" your int in byte array. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585532/c-int-to-byte-array

Answer (score 0):

If your are trying to add a short value (2 Bytes), you could do that

```
B2.append((char)((myint & 0xFF00) >> 8));
B2.append((char)(myint & 0x00FF));
```

It will append the short value in big endian order