# Printing out byte stream in C++

Tags: c++, format, int, data-conversion

With the help of this site, [C++ int to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585532/c-int-to-byte-array), I have a code to serialize int to byte stream.

The byte stream data from integer value 1234 is '\x00\x00\x04\xd2' in big endian format, and I need to come up with an utility function to display the byte stream. This is my first version.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

std::vector<unsigned char> intToBytes(int value)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> result;
    result.push_back(value >> 24);
    result.push_back(value >> 16);
    result.push_back(value >>  8);
    result.push_back(value      );
    return result;
}

void print(const std::vector<unsigned char> input)
{
    for (auto val : input)
        cout << val; // <-- 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<unsigned char> st(intToBytes(1234));
    print(st);
}
```

How can I get correct value on the screen both in decimal and hex?

Comment: Use the `std::hex()` IO manipulator

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For hex:

```
for (auto val : input) printf("\\x%.2x", val);
```

For decimal:

```
for (auto val : input) printf("%d ", val);
```

Comment: +1, although I can almost guarantee that someone's going to mark you down for using C-style printf rather than C++ streams.  Even though for this sort of thing the printf solution is clearer...

Comment: Thanks. Even Google C++ Code Style Guide recommends `printf` against `std::cout`, and I personally agree.

Comment: Indeed it does, although it does that not because one is unequivocally better than the other, but simply because they had to choose something...

Comment: Shouldn't you use `%02x` instead of `%.2x`?

Comment: For integer specifiers, it's the same. I'm just used to `%.2x`, but probably `%02x` is more self-explaining.