# Appending an Int to a char * in C

Tags: c, concatenation, encryption

So I am looking to append the length of a cipher text onto the end of the char array that I am storing the cipher in.  I am not a native to C and below is a test snippet of what I have devised that I *think* works.

```
...
int cipherTextLength = 0;
unsigned char *cipherText = NULL;
...
EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(&encryptCtx, cipherText + cipherTextLength, &finalBlockLength);
cipherTextLength += finalBlockLength;
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&encryptCtx);

// Append the length of the cipher text onto the end of the cipher text
// Note, the length stored will never be anywhere near 4294967295 
char cipherLengthChar[1];
sprintf(cipherLengthChar, "%d", cipherTextLength);
strcat(cipherText, cipherLengthChar);
printf("ENC - cipherTextLength: %d\n", cipherTextLength);
...
```

The problem is I don't think using `strcat` when dealing with binary data is going to be trouble free.  Could anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Ok, so I'll add a little context as to why I was looking to append the length.  In my `encrypt` function, the function `EVP_EncryptUpdate` requires the length of the `plainText` being encrypted.  As this is much more easy to obtain, this part isn't a problem.  However, similarly, using `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex` in my `decrypt` function requires the length of the `ciperText` being decrypted, so I need to store it somewhere.

In the application where I am implementing this, all I am doing is changing some poor hashing to proper encryption.  To add further hassle, the way the application is I first need to decrypt information read in from XML, do something with it, then encrypt it and rewrite it to XML again, so I need to have this cipher length stored in the cipher somehow.  I also don't have scope to redesign this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of what you are doing now, it may be smarter to encode the ciphertext size to a location *before* the ciphertext itself. Once you start decrypting, it is not very useful to find the size at the end. You need to know the end to get the size to find the end, not very helpful.

Furthermore, the ciphertext is binary, so you don't need to convert anything to string. You would like to convert it to a fixed number of bytes (otherwise you don't know the size of the size :P ). So create a bigger buffer (4 bytes more than you require for the ciphertext), and start encrypting to offset 4 forwards. Then copy the size of the ciphertext in at the start of the buffer.

If you don't know how to encode an integer, take a look at - for instance - [this question/ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585532/c-int-to-byte-array). Note, this will only encode 32 bits for a maximum size of the ciphertext of `2^32`, about 4 GiB. Furthermore, the link pointed to use Big Endian encoding. You should use either Big Endian (preferred for crypto code) or Little Endian encoding - but don't mix the two.

Neither the ciphertext nor the encoded size should be used as a character string. If you need a character string, my suggestion is to base 64 encode the buffer up to the end of the ciphertext.

Comment: Yeah after reading the other comments I decided to prepend the length.  I like the idea of offsetting the buffer, so that I know where the cipher text will start.  Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are having enough big arrays both for cipherText and cipheLegthChar to store the required text. Hence instead of

```
unsigned char *cipherText = NULL;
```

You can have

```
unsigned char cipherText[MAX_TEXT];
```

similarly for

```
cipherLenghthChar[MAX_INT];
```

Or you can have them dynamically allocated.

where MAX_TEXT and MAX_INT max buffer size to store text and integer. Also after first call of EVP_EncryptFinal_ex NULL terminate cipherText so that you strcat works.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is I don't think using strcat when dealing with binary data is going to be trouble free.

Correct!  That's not your only problem though:

```
// Note, the length stored will never be anywhere near 4294967295 
char cipherLengthChar[1];
sprintf(cipherLengthChar, "%d", cipherTextLength);
```

Even if `cipherTextLength` is 0 here, you've gone out of bounds, since `sprintf` will add a null terminator, making a total of two chars -- but `cipherLengthChar` only has room for one.
If you consider, e.g. 4294967295, as a string, that's 10 chars + `'\0'` = 11 chars.

It would appear that `finalBlockLength` is the length of the data put into `cipherText`.  However, the `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex()` call will probably fail in one way or another, or at least not do what you want, since `cipherText == NULL`.  You then add 0 to that (== 0 aka. still NULL) and submit it as a parameter.  Either you need a pointer to a pointer there (if `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex` is going to allocate space for you), or else you have to make sure there is enough room in `cipherText` to start with.

With regard to tacking text (or whatever) onto the end, you can just use sprintf directly:

```
sprintf(cipherText + finalBlockLength, "%d", cipherTextLength);
```

Presuming that `cipherText` is non-NULL and has enough *extra* room in it (see first couple of paragraphs).

However, I'm very dubious that doing that will be useful later on, but since I don't have any further context, I can't say more.