# How to cast an int array to a byte array in c++

Tags: c++

hey i would like to know how you could cast an Int array in C++ to an byte array and what would be the declaration method. I would appreciate if it is simpler and no use of pointers. thanks for the comments

Comment: Please, look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve first.

Comment: [Integer to byte Array conversion Code][1]
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5585683/5250973

Comment: You will need to be more specific about your requirements. What do you envision the end result looking like? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a bit less convenient but maybe a bit more understandable from your perspective:

```
std::array<int, 3> arr_ints = {1, 2, 3};
std::array<unsigned char, 3> arr_bytes;

for(unsigned i=0; i<arr_ints.size(); ++i)
    arr_bytes[i] = static_cast<unsigned char>(arr_ints[i]);
```

Comment: `0 | arr_ints[i]`does not make much sense, does it? Is it intended to suppress a cast warning? Then a real cast would be much better.

Comment: Changed it to an explicit cast!